# Почему Task<V> не запускается снова?

Tags: java, javafx

Мне нужно, чтобы при вызове метода pause() поток task останавливался, а при последующем выполнении условия if(ChoiceRe.getText()=="Обычный") он возобновлялся. Но вот этот код этого не выполняет

```
    if(ChoiceRe.getText()=="Обычный"){
        System.out.println("Обычный режим запущен");
        normalTime=normalTime*60000;
        normalTime=normalTime/100;
        f=new FileInputStream("src//application//res//Re//NormalRe//NormalReChild.mp3");
        if(pause==true){
             task3 = new Task<Void>() {

                @Override
                public Void call() throws Exception {
                    double TimeStart = 0d;
                    for (int row = 0; row < 100; row++) {
                        TimeStart = TimeStart + 0.01;
                        updateProgress(TimeStart, 1);
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(normalTime);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            return null;
                        }
                    }
                    return null;
                }
            };
            time.progressProperty().bind(task3.progressProperty());
            Executors.newCachedThreadPool().submit(task3);
            pause=false;
        } else {
            task = new Task<Void>() {

              @Override
              public Void call() throws Exception {
                 double TimeStart = 0d;
                 for (int row = 0; row < 100; row++) {
                    TimeStart = TimeStart + 0.01;
                    updateProgress(TimeStart, 1);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(normalTime);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        return null;
                    }
                 }
                 return null;
              }
           };
           time.progressProperty().bind(task.progressProperty());
           Executors.newCachedThreadPool().submit(task);
        }
        Task<Void> task2 = new Task<Void>() {

            @Override
            protected Void call() throws Exception {
                while(time.getProgress()!=1.0){
                    if(time.getProgress()==0.03){
                        try {
                            Player p=new Player(f);
                            p.play();
                        } catch (JavaLayerException e) {}
                    }
                 }
                return null;
            }
        };
        Executors.newCachedThreadPool().submit(task2);
    }
}

public void pause(){
    task.cancel(true);
    pause=true;
}
```

Comment: А что будет делать ваша готовая программа? Мне просто кажется, что вы пытаетесь сделать что-то простое, но при этом не знаете как и сооружаете нечто безумное. Ответы сообщества помогут вам больше, если сообщество будет знать конечную цель.

Comment: У меня будет ProgressIndicator, который начнёт заполнятся при нажатии кнопки "пуск" и останавливаться на кнопку "стоп"(pause()).

Comment: на всякий случай замечу, что task.cancel(true) по сути вызывает Thread.interrupt(). Возможно вам стоит передавать какой-нибудь управляющий mutable объект в ваш таск, менять его состояние снаружи и проверять его при выполнении таска

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы возобновить какую-то работу, нужно где-то хранить состояние этой работы. Как вы утверждаете, работа состоит в том, чтобы менять `ProgressIndicator`, который сам хранит свое состояние, поэтому можно сделать так:

```
if ( !pause ) { // первый запуск?
    // сбрасываем индикатор до 0
    time.progressProperty().unbind();
    time.progressProperty().set( 0.0 );
}


task = new Task<Void>() { // создаем новое задание
    // берем текущее состояние ProgressIndicator
    double TimeStart = time.getProgress();
    {
        // обновляем начальный прогресс задания,
        // чтобы не дернуть индикатор в bind
        updateProgress(TimeStart, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public Void call() throws Exception {
        try {
            // пока не доработали до 1.0, увеличиваем, обновляем прогресс, спим.
            while( TimeStart < 1 ) {
                TimeStart = TimeStart + 0.01;
                updateProgress(TimeStart, 1);
                Thread.sleep(normalTime);
            }
        // если придет InterruptedException (от task.cancel()), вываливаемся из цикла
        } catch (InterruptedException e) { 
            /* e.printStackTrace(); */
        }
        return null;
    }
};
time.progressProperty().bind(task.progressProperty());

// не надо плодить новый ExecutorService на каждый чих, лучше
// создать 1 и обращаться к нему по необходимости
executor.submit(task);
pause = false;
```

Пауза:

```
public void pause() {
    // отмена - отвязываем индикатор от таска
    time.progressProperty().unbind();
    task.cancel(); // отменяем таск
    pause = true;
}
```